# Multiple Switch components are changing order in a List element when being pressed

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a screen where the user is able to enable/disable specific push notifications. When a user presses on a toggle the correct toggle is changed and the state is being updated.

The issue that I have is that after the switch happened it does some strange ordering. See the video [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d9r6.jpg) (I'm sorry about the video quality, tried to execute it with this command: `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo toggle.mp4`).

**Component state**

```
state = {
    defaultNotifications: {
      config_error: { active: true, normalized: 'Notifiy on configuration error' },
      on_first_start: { active: true, normalized: 'Notifiy on first start' },
      on_trigger: { active: true, normalized: 'Notifiy on trigger' },
      on_panic_start: { active: true, normalized: 'Notifiy on panic start' },
      on_panic_end: { active: true, normalized: 'Notifiy on panic sell end' },
      order_placed: { active: true, normalized: 'Notifiy on order placed' },
      trade_completed: { active: true, normalized: 'Notifiy on trade completed' },
      order_cancelled: { active: true, normalized: 'Notifiy on order cancelled' },
    }
  }
```

**Toggle function**

```
const enabledNotifications = [];
const stateNotifications = this.state.defaultNotifications;
Object.keys(stateNotifications).forEach((notification) => {
  if (stateNotifications[notification].active) {
    enabledNotifications.push(notification);
  }
});
```

I needed a comma separated string with the 'active' notification names for a POST request later:

```
const requestBody = qs.stringify({
  player_id: this.state.playerId,
  permissions: enabledNotifications.toString()
}, { arrayFormat: 'comma', encode: false });
```

**Change the toggle to !active**

```
toggleNotification = (notification) => {
    this.setState({ defaultNotifications: {
      ...this.state.defaultNotifications,
      [notification]: {
        ...this.state.defaultNotifications[notification],
        active: !this.state.defaultNotifications[notification].active,
      }
    } });
  };
```

**Toggle in JSX**

```
    const userNotifications = this.state.defaultNotifications;

    return (
      Object.keys(userNotifications).map((notification) =>
        <ListItem
        key={notification}
        >
          <Image
            style={{ width: 24, height: 24 }}
            source={require('../../../assets/more_icons/notify_green.png')}
          />
          <Text style={styles.notificationText}>
            { userNotifications[notification].normalized }
          </Text>
          <Switch
             onValueChange={() => this.toggleNotification(notification)}
             value={userNotifications[notification].active}
             style={{ marginLeft: 'auto' }}
           />
        </ListItem>
      )
    );
```

I remember that I did clear my XCode Simulator cache with `xcrun simctl erase all`, a few minutes before this error occurred. But I can't think of any reason why that would cause any related issues.

Comment: Hello
Kindly follow my answers here
it will help you to achieve same
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53368506/react-native-how-to-use-flatlist-to-create-multiple-switches/53368576#53368576

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not guarantee the order of properties when iterating through an objects's properties. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/3599151). So you cannot be sure that the keys are returned in the way you anticipate right now, and that can lead to random changes while rendering.

So my recommendation is to order the object keys actively prior to displaying them. For example, to sort them alphabetically:

```
Object.keys(userNotifications).sort().map((notification) => ...
```

Alternatively, you could use an ordered array you set yourself:

```
['config_error', 'on_first_start', 'on_trigger', 'on_panic_start', 'on_panic_end', 'order_placed', 'trade_completed', 'order_cancelled'].map(key => userNotifications[key]).map((notification) => ...
```